# Knockout.js mapping plugin how to update data

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

The following code will fetch and bind the JSON data correctly to the view but when I GET updated data the view will not update. The data has changed but the view doesn't update. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I have trouble understanding how the mapping plugin works.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

setInterval(LeaderboardViewModel, (10 * 500));

function LeaderboardViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.ArrayOfPlayers = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:5500/leaderboard/',
        context: this,
        success: function(data) {
          self.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax(data);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    this.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax = function(data) {
        var array = $.map(data.leaderboard, function(value, index) {
            return [value];
        });

        console.log(array);
        ko.mapping.fromJS(array, {}, self.ArrayOfPlayers);  
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new LeaderboardViewModel());

});
```

The following HTML renders the data correctly when I load the page:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: ArrayOfPlayers">
```

EDIT: When I load the page it works correctly. the set interval part doesn't work.

GET data:

```
{
  "leaderboard": {
"1": {
  "deaths": 52, 
  "game_count": 13, 
  "game_defeats": 0, 
  "game_deserts": 0, 
  "game_draws": 0, 
  "game_wins": 13, 
  "id": 2, 
  "kills": 78, 
  "level": 8, 
  "rank": 1, 
  "xp": 3260
}, 
"10": {
  "deaths": 78, 
  "game_count": 13, 
  "game_defeats": 13, 
  "game_deserts": 0, 
  "game_draws": 0, 
  "game_wins": 0, 
  "id": 1, 
  "kills": 52, 
  "level": 5, 
  "rank": 10, 
  "xp": 1570
}, 
}
```

EDIT 2: no console errors.

Comment: Is it also not working for the first time, or only when invoked by `setInterval`?

Comment: What does the data from the GET request look like?

Comment: Also, just to make sure, are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you use keyword 'new' for applyBinding, but set timeout to function definition.
It must work in this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

function LeaderboardViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.ArrayOfPlayers = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);

    this.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax = function(data) {
        var array = $.map(data.leaderboard, function(value, index) {
            return [value];
        });

        console.log(array);
        ko.mapping.fromJS(array, {}, self.ArrayOfPlayers);  
    };

    self.UpdateMappings = function(){
         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: 'http://localhost:5500/leaderboard/',
             context: this,
             success: function(data) {
               self.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax(data);
             },
             dataType: 'json'
        });
    };      
}

var viewModel = new LeaderboardViewModel();
setInterval(viewModel.UpdateMappings, (10 * 500));

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});
```